# How to test binary post uploaded file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, upload, carrierwave

I am currently testing if uploaded file is the same as original file.
The api requires upload body to be binary, not multipart/form-data.

This is the spec:

```
  it "uploads" do
    fixture_path = Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/")
    fixture_file = fixture_path.join("landscape.jpg")
    file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(fixture_file, "image/jpeg", :binary)
    post api_upload_upload_path, file, header
    assert_response :success
  end
```

When I run the spec, it fails:

```
Failures:

  1) Api::V1::UploadController uploads
     Failure/Error: post api_upload_upload_path, file, company_header
     ArgumentError:
       invalid %-encoding (These are bad characters
```

How to fix this?
or, Is there any better way to test this kind of action?

Comment: is that the full error? what is the value of `header`?

Comment: @UriAgassi I've figured it out. It's because browser is hard to post an image. AngularJS puts it into multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. It's because browser is hard to post an image. AngularJS puts it into multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found a solution! In Rails 6+ you should also be able to achieve a binary upload by setting the `body` arg on `#post`:

```
file = file_fixture('landscape.jpg')
post api_upload_path, body: file.binread, as: :binary
```